# RSelenium Throwing Error on initializing : - HTTP 403

Tags: r, selenium

I am using `RSelenium` package in my Ubuntu machine (server). However when I run function `rsDriver()` for initialization, I stuck with below error:

```
> library(RSelenium)
> rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', verbose = T)
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 403.
```

Any idea how to resolve this error would be highly helpful.

*R session info :*

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RSelenium_1.7.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     XML_3.99-0       binman_0.1.1     assertthat_0.2.0
 [5] rappdirs_0.3.1   bitops_1.0-6     R6_2.3.0         jsonlite_1.5
 [9] semver_0.2.0     httr_1.3.1       curl_3.2         xml2_1.2.0
[13] tools_3.4.4      wdman_0.2.4      yaml_2.2.0       compiler_3.4.4
[17] caTools_1.17.1.1 openssl_1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into what appears to be the exact same issue. After inspecting the arguments for the *rsDriver()* function and realizing I was getting the error during the geckodriver version check (as are you), I decided to what other gecko versions were available. Using the code suggested in the *rsDriver* help section (geckover = what version of Gecko driver to run. Default = "latest" which runs the most recent version. To see other version currently sourced run binman::list_versions("geckodriver")), A value of NULL excludes adding the firefox browser to Selenium Server) I ran *binman::list_versions("geckodriver")*. I got the following output *"0.20.1" "0.21.0" "0.22.0" "0.23.0"*. Then, using the second latest version, I subbed "0.22.0" into the *geckover* argument and everything appears to be running smoothly.